# Symfony 2.3 authenticate against rest api

Tags: php, rest, symfony, authentication

This is my first question in stackoverflow.

I am new with PHP and Symfony, and i´m trying to login a user against Backendless REST API using email and password (in a form). That service responses with a token i need to use in future API calls. I want to use Symfony security component for this.

I have searched in stackoverflow and found this article, http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/, but i have some problems i don´t know how to solve and i would appreciate any help.

1. I need to save the Backendless token after successful login. I am not using any database (Backendless has all the data), but i have to save it somewhere (session? security.context?, but i have no idea how to access the session from the Service that handles authentication (in the post is called Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Service, authenticate method), neither if i need to create a custom token and how to use it.
2. How to avoid calling loadUserByUsername in every page? The post author suggest to save it in session, but again i have no idea how to access session from the authentication provider to save it once is logeed in. Besides, i don´t know if there is other way to do this.

Somebody upload the post code to github, https://github.com/gezpage/sf2testproject/tree/webserviceauth.

Hope somebody can help me, i would appreciate it.

Comment: Check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html , specifically the "Storing Authentication in the Session" section.

Comment: Hi @Qoop. What i have to do is return the same $user in refreshUser received as parameter? I don´t get it very well.

Comment: From looking at that it does look like that.. as a minimum. Although without getting the user from the database and doing a check for if it had been changed on the client side i don't think it would be too secure.

Comment: For what i am doing, i think i don´t need to reload the user once it is authenticated. Maybe this can work ... What i still don´t know is, from the code in the linked post, how can i save the backendless token in session after login user in the checkAuthentication method ...

Comment: Have you read it all? It says to set the firewalls `stateless` option to `false` which will cause it to serialize the token (and user) into the session. Then on the next request it will call refreshUser with the deserialized user from the session. The reason to reload the user would be that you would then be trusting the client side session entirely rather than checking whether the user has been messed with at all, but that's up to you.

Comment: I have read it but i don´t get it very well. I am working against a REST API, so i think it would be a little expensive to reload user from API every time, but if it is necessary, i guess i can do it. My main problem is still to figure out how to save the token from the checkAuthentication to the session.

Comment: It does it automatically when you set it to not be stateless. You don't need to load font the database on each call but if you don't a user could change the data on the session (for example, change their role to super admin) and you would have no way of knowing.

Comment: Ok, now i get your point. I think that, for this specific case, that won´t happen, but i guess i will know for sure when running some tests. Thanks for your help @Qoop, i think point 2 is solved. Do you have any idea or recommendation for point 1? I need to save that token somewhere but i don´t know how.

Comment: The token is auto saved in the security context which is serialized into the session.

Comment: I mean the token i get from REST API. From the code i am using (http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/), i don´t get it. If login is done inside this method, $this->service->authenticate($token->getUser(), $presentedPassword), i don´t know how is it auto saved because i understand that method only gives true/false. I am new with PHP and Symfony, sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: You already have the token, it's passed into the `checkAuthentication(UserInterface $user, UsernamePasswordToken $token)`.

Comment: I don´t get it :'( ... I think i am explaining really bad. In checkAuthentificacion, i make a call to Backendless REST API sending email and password, to get an alphanumeric code that i need to use in future API calls. That code is associated to the user and i want to save it somewhere, but i don´t know how to do it inside the checkAuthentification method.